# Run sudo command with non-root user in Docker container

Tags: sudo, docker

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.04

# Must have packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano zsh curl git

# Instal Oh my Zsh
RUN bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
RUN sed -i -- 's/robbyrussell/sonicradish/g' /root/.zshrc 

# Add none root user
RUN adduser admin
USER admin
```

I'm connecting with the admin user with the zsh shell.

```
docker exec -ti linux zsh
```

I'm adding a non-root user (admin).

I still want to execute a `sudo` command with this user, but it errors out:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim
zsh: command not found: sudo
```

Same message with bash shell.

How can I run `sudo` commands with a non-root user?

When I don't use `sudo` I get a permission error:

```
$ apt-get install vim
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: did you try [`ssh`ing into the container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/#build-an-egsshd-image)?

Comment: @EliranMalka What's the point of SSH in a container? `exec bash` is the "more correct way" to get into a container

Comment: @Kevin What command do you actually want to run? You have `nano` already being installed, so why try to install `vim`? And if you want `vim`, then install it

Comment: vim is just an example. I just want to be able to install stuff as an none root user in my docker container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `sudo` to your install list; most Docker containers don't ship with it. I don't know about Ubuntu, but I know that's the case with Fedora and CentOS.

Comment: it works but now I have this message when I want to install something with the sudo command and the admin user `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: That can be fixed by editing `/etc/sudoers`. And it's another question. Since this answered yours, please check the box and "accept" it. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21659637/836748